# The best softwares to understand the intersections of the 3D objects in the Euclidean space

Tags: geometry, soft-question, math-software

What is the best software (Easy to follow and clear graphics) to draw the intersections between two spheres, Two spheres and a pyramid, for example.

The centre and the radius of the spheres are given in Euclidean coordinates.

Comment: Almost any 3D CAD system.

Answer (score 1):

Winplot is a very acessible and user-friendly. You can download it for free here: http://math.exeter.edu/rparris/winplot.html